# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type, c# MVC, functions in RAZOR FORMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, lambda, entity

I want to pass some parameter(id) to my functions in Razor forms like this:

```
c.For(m =>@ProgData(m.Id)).Order(4);
```

This is sample of the functions:

```
@functions{
    string ProgData(int id) 
    {
        string result="ss"; 
        return result;
    }
}
```

and object "m" values

```
{"Id":161,"Name":"Поступление Тест","Status":1,"Date":"\/Date(1501092000000)\/","Sum":{"Value":10000,"HasValue":true},"Invoice":true,"ContractorId":191,"ContractorTypeUid":"3325eab1-fe46-4900-a617-c6fb54ac24c0","ContractorName":"BAS конвертация","SaleId":264,"SaleName":"Тестовая сделка для КП и ПК (консалтинг)","SaleStatus":1,"ResponsibleId":506,"ResponsibleUid":"2410b44e-8c98-4cc6-a47e-5ff12ed9c58b","ResponsibleFirstName":"Nurkassym","ResponsibleLastName":"Bakhramov","ResponsibleMiddleName":null,"CreationAuthorId":506,"CreationAuthorUid":"2410b44e-8c98-4cc6-a47e-5ff12ed9c58b","CreationAuthorFirstName":"Nurkassym","CreationAuthorLastName":"Bakhramov","CreationAuthorMiddleName":null,"IsSaleClosed":false,"ResponsibleShortName":"Bakhramov N.","CreationAuthorShortName":"Bakhramov N."}
```

However it is throwing the error 'Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type'.

Anybody know a way round this error?

View file screen:
[image]

Comment: I cannot recall `.For` extension method. What is `c` in your code? Please, also show `using` statements from the beginning of your Razor view file.

Comment: My guess is that you did not add a `using` for correct namespace which provides lambda overload for `.For` method and it expects a string like `.For("Id")`.